# File copying time variations

Tags: linux, operating-system, filesystems

Does it take longer to copy many small files compared to 1 large file both totaling of same size? Is it just because of the overhead for copying details of each file?

Comment: Each file requires a directory update, to start with, so many small files will require many directory updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it takes more time to copy many small files as compared to copying the same amount of data in one large file.

And yes, the overhead comes from having to manage all the file system entries and metadata.